# Sync laravel with SMF

Tags: laravel, smf

i have one question. How or is possible to store data from **SMF SSI (api)** into Laravel Auth. Is there way to sync that two script or any other way to store data from SMF and use as *Auth::* throw framework website beside forum script.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by creating Helpers provider where i create static function in which i add info from smf_members and using that data.

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

class User
{

    public static function info()
    {
        global $user_info;
        $user_id = $user_info['id'];
        if ($user_id == 0) {
            return "Guest";
        } else {
            return "Logged in";
        }
    }
}
```